# How to mix charts views and table views on the same page?

Tags: views, charts

I have a view with data displayed in a table format, and I have created another view formatted as a chart. For the view containing the chart, I used the views display style 'Charts', which was added as an additional views style by enabling the [Charts module](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts).

How can I display these two separated views on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer to this question for anybody using the [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module is contained in [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929), located within its community documentation.

Here is part of the **Bonus Tip** included in it:

> You may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it
>   to a chart display after setting up the data. It can be easier to
>   visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out
>   in a table first.

Refer to "Example 2" in my answer to "[How to create a chart from simple data without using the Views aggregation feature?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194376/how-to-create-a-chart-from-simple-data-without-using-the-views-aggregation-featu/194496#194496)" for an illustration of this approach (which also includes a view in export format to start from).

Another approach is to [use module Panels to show charts created with module Charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426917).

Here are some other (related) documentation pages for the charts module, which may help to get you going with the charts module:

- [Getting Started](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423033).
- [Create Charts using views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837).
- [Charts Howtos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2435077).

Comment: I have solved this problem by using panel

Answer (score 1):

You do not need panels just to display two views on the same page. Although you can certainly use them for that purpose (and you get the typical advantages of using panels, such as layout features, etc). It is very easy to achieve two views on the same page, just by using the 'attachment' display in views itself.

Here is how you go about it:

1. Create a view as usual with display page. Set up as you want (Eg. using  **charts** as its format).
2. Add a second display to the same view, of the type 'attachment' and set it up as you want (Eg. using **table** as its format) ... Be careful not to override your first view!
3. In Attachment setting chose attach to 'page'.

You can set other options such as to display the attachment before or after the view it is attached to and if contextual/exposed filters should be inherited.

Just remember that your page and your attachment can use different formats. Eg. one can be a table and another a chart (and you could also swap the formats as suggested in step 1 and 2 above).