# How to create a chart from simple data without using the Views aggregation feature?

Tags: 7, views, entities, charts

I am trying to create a chart from really simple data. I am using the highcharts library and the [Visualization API](https://www.drupal.org/project/visualization) module and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). It seems like the only type of graphs that I see examples of on the Internet involve aggregation. For example, someone wants to find the number of taxonomy terms used in the nodes of a particular content type and they use a pie chart to show the percentage (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot2cFQVgzfA&spfreload=1).

The type of data I am trying to visualize is something like this.

```
  Year   Products
+------+----------+
| 2015 +    78    +
+------+----------+
| 2014 +    74    +
+------+----------+
| 2013 +   123    +
+------+----------+
| 2012 +   106    +
+------+----------+
| 2011 +    59    +
+------+----------+ 
|  ... +    ...   +
```

I want my x-axis to be Year and my y-axis to be Sales. My content type has each of these fields. In views I am only including the years field and the sales field, which are both integers.

If I view the data as an HTML Grid I see this at the bottom of the views page:

```
Title
Test

Content
2015
78

2014
74

2013
123

2012
106

2011
59
```

So it looks like view is showing both fields. But when I use Visualization (Highcharts) - Line Chart instead of HTML Grid I get:

[image: Test Chart]

The query produced by views is:

```
SELECT TOP(10) node.[nid] AS [nid], node.[created] AS [node_created], 'node' AS field_data_field_year_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_products_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE ( (( ([node].[status] = '1') AND ([node].[type] IN  ('year')) )) )
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

This makes me think views cannot do a JOIN to get the results from both the node and the product field tables. Instead it is using node as a text value, not an integer, so the chart shows values of zero. Interestingly in views the HTML Chart format can get the values, just not the Visualization format.

How can I create a simple chart based on two columns of data using Highcharts and Visualization?

Here is the export of my actual view (some field names are different than my example):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'field_year' => 'field_year',
  'field_agricultural_related_produ' => 'field_agricultural_related_produ',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'field_year' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_agricultural_related_produ' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Year */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['id'] = 'field_year';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['table'] = 'field_data_field_year';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['field'] = 'field_year';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['settings'] = array(
  'thousand_separator' => '',
  'prefix_suffix' => 1,
  'date_conditional_display_field' => '',
  'date_conditional_display_pre_text' => '',
  'date_conditional_display_post_text' => '',
  'linked_field' => array(
    'linked' => 0,
    'destination' => '',
    'advanced' => array(
      'title' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'class' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'text' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_year']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Products */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['id'] = 'field_agricultural_related_produ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['table'] = 'field_data_field_agricultural_related_produ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['field'] = 'field_agricultural_related_produ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['settings'] = array(
  'thousand_separator' => '',
  'prefix_suffix' => 1,
  'date_conditional_display_field' => '',
  'date_conditional_display_pre_text' => '',
  'date_conditional_display_post_text' => '',
  'linked_field' => array(
    'linked' => 0,
    'destination' => '',
    'advanced' => array(
      'title' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'class' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'text' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_agricultural_related_produ']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'year' => 'year',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'testvisualization';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part 1: From the Charts documentation

The tabular data for which you're trying to create a chart looks pretty similar to the tabular data of this variation (with it's corresponding ***area chart*** below it):

[image]

The above screenprint is from [Preview 4: Area chart created with the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426177#preview4), which was created using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.

[Preview 3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426177#preview3) of that same community documentation page has another sample which shows a pie chart (created with either Google Charts or HighCharts as charting engine, which looks like so:

[image]

So if you're willing to consider using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module it should be pretty forward to get this to work. If needed refer to its Community documentation for (way) more details.

If you still can't get it to work, then try the "***bonus tip***" mentioned in [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://drupal.org/node/2426929) (= first create a tabular version of the data you want to chart, to make sure that the input for creating the chart is actually correct). That may help to refine your view before actually creating the chart.

## Part 2: Online Charts demonstration

#### Example 1

Have a look at [Single chart, not attached to a table, and without aggregation](http://drupal.placeto.be/single_chart_with_no_aggregation_not_attached_to_table). Here is a quote from it:

> The chart below (created using the "charts" module) shows all nodes of content type "Article", which has 2 fields with these "machine names" (+ values):
>
> - "`field_optionlist`" (with some select list values, such as the "year")
> - "`field_free_format_text`" (assumed to contain some numeric values)

I trust you agree it looks pretty close (identical?) to the chart you're trying to create. And in this case it does not (repeat: **not**) use any views aggregation facilities.

Here is the exported view that is used to create this (example 1) chart:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'visualization_no_aggregation_ex1;
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Visualization no aggregation example1';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Single chart, not attached to a table, and without aggregation';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['type'] = 'line';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => 'field_free_format_text',
  'body' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'body' => '#2f7ed8',
  'field_free_format_text' => '#233a99',
);
/* Header: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['content'] = 'The chart below (created using the "charts" module) shows all nodes of content type "Article", which has 2 fields with these "machine names" (+ values):

- "field_optionlist" (with some select list values, such as the "year")
- "field_free_format_text" (assumed to contain some numeric values)';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
/* Field: Content: Free Format Text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['id'] = 'field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['table'] = 'field_data_field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['field'] = 'field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['label'] = 'Products';
/* Field: Content: OptionList */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['id'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['table'] = 'field_data_field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['field'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['label'] = 'Year';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'article' => 'article',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: OptionList (field_optionlist) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_optionlist_value']['id'] = 'field_optionlist_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_optionlist_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_optionlist_value']['field'] = 'field_optionlist_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_optionlist_value']['value'] = array(
  13 => '13',
  14 => '14',
  15 => '15',
);

/* Display: Chart */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Chart', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['type'] = 'column';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['xaxis_title'] = 'Year';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['yaxis_title'] = 'Nr of Products';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => 'field_free_format_text',
  'field_optionlist' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => '#7b0d49',
  'field_optionlist' => '#8bbc21',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'single_chart_with_no_aggregation_not_attached_to_table';
```

#### Example 2

But wait, there is more ... i.e. another example. Actually a slightly enhanced version of the previous one. Have a look at [Table with attached charts, and without aggregation](http://drupal.placeto.be/table_with_attached_charts_and_no_aggregation). It's similar to the previous example, but on the same page it also includes that tabular view of the data in the chart, and it actually includes 2 variations of such chart (a line chart and a column chart).

Here is the exported view that is used to create this (example 2) chart:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'visualization_no_aggregation_ex2';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Visualization no aggregation ex2';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Table with attached charts, and without aggregation';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['type'] = 'line';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => 'field_free_format_text',
  'body' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'body' => '#2f7ed8',
  'field_free_format_text' => '#233a99',
);
/* Footer: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area']['content'] = 'The above table shows all nodes of content type "Article", which has 2 fields with these "machine" names (and their values):
- field_optionlist (with some select list values, such as the "year")
- field_free_format_text (assumed to contain some numeric values)';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
/* Field: Content: OptionList */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['id'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['table'] = 'field_data_field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['field'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_optionlist']['label'] = 'Year';
/* Field: Content: Free Format Text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['id'] = 'field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['table'] = 'field_data_field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['field'] = 'field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_free_format_text']['label'] = 'Products';
/* Sort criterion: Content: OptionList (field_optionlist) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_optionlist_value']['id'] = 'field_optionlist_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_optionlist_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_optionlist_value']['field'] = 'field_optionlist_value';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'article' => 'article',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Free Format Text (field_free_format_text) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_free_format_text_value']['id'] = 'field_free_format_text_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_free_format_text_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_free_format_text';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_free_format_text_value']['field'] = 'field_free_format_text_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_free_format_text_value']['operator'] = 'not empty';

/* Display: Table */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Table', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => 'field_free_format_text',
  'field_optionlist' => 'field_optionlist',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_optionlist' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['header'] = FALSE;
/* Header: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['content'] = 'The table below shows all nodes of content type "Article", which has 2 fields with these "machine names" (+ values):

- "field_optionlist" (with some select list values, such as the "year")
- "field_free_format_text" (assumed to contain some numeric values)';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['footer'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'table_with_attached_charts_and_no_aggregation';

/* Display: Line Chart */
$handler = $view->new_display('attachment', 'Line Chart', 'attachment_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['type'] = 'line';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => 'field_free_format_text',
  'field_optionlist' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'field_optionlist' => '#008040',
  'field_free_format_text' => '#ff8000',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['header'] = FALSE;
/* Header: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['content'] = 'Below is a <strong>chart</strong> about the very same data (as in the table above), in the format of the "<strong>line chart</strong>", and which is "<strong>attached</strong>" to the tabular view above.';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['footer'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'page' => 'page',
  'default' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['attachment_position'] = 'after';

/* Display: Column Chart */
$handler = $view->new_display('attachment', 'Column Chart', 'attachment_2');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['type'] = 'column';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'field_optionlist';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'field_free_format_text' => 'field_free_format_text',
  'field_optionlist' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'field_optionlist' => '#2f7ed8',
  'field_free_format_text' => '#233a99',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['header'] = FALSE;
/* Header: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['content'] = 'Below is a <strong>yet another chart</strong> about the very same data (as in the table above), in the format of the "<strong>column chart</strong>", and which is "<strong>attached</strong>" (also) to the tabular view above.';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['footer'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'page' => 'page',
  'default' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['attachment_position'] = 'after';
```

**For both examples above** (the exported views): these are the changes you need to make before you'll be able to successfully import those views in your environment:

1. Adapt the machine names of the 2 field names to match your field names (which I saw in your exported view), ie:

   - change `field_optionlist` to `field_year`.
   - change `field_free_format_text` to `field_agricultural_related_produ`.
2. Adapt the content type's machine name from `article` to `year` (that's your machine name I saw in your exported view).
3. Pretty sure you do want to delete (remove) the line with `/* Filter criterion: Content: OptionList (field_optionlist) */`, and 8 lines following that line containing values like 13, 14 and 15 (I added that extra filter to limit my results to only 3 relevant "articles").

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.

Comment: Thanks, however, whether I use the Visualization Module or the Charts Module, I still get the same results.  Using the Charts module, in views if I select Content: Year for PROVIDES LABELS and Content: Products for PROVIDES DATA I get a list of years on the x-axis and a zero value (straight horizontal line) for each product.  If I chose the opposide for PROVIDES LABELS and PROVIDES DATA I get a list of values on the x-axis and zero values for the years (straight horizontal line).

Comment: That sounds like something "else" is wrong in the view you created that contains the data you are trying to chart. Have a look at the "**bonus tip**" I just added to my answer, to ensure that your data to be charted are correct.

Comment: Pierre, would it be possible to see your content type for the data in Preview 4 on https://www.drupal.org/node/2426177?

Comment: Pierre, one of your tips on the Steps to create charts using the views UI page says use aggregation.  As you see in the title of my post, I am not using aggregation because I do not need to aggregate data, I am just trying to display two columns of simple data (year and value) in a chart.

Comment: Pierre, In your bonus tip on that page you mention trying a Table.  I did so and the table looks fine: two columns, left column is years and right column is values.  Still the charts look wrong.

Comment: Give me some more time (probably until tomorrow) to create a demo sample you can look at (using Charts), and that should be close (identical) to what you're trying to create. for now know that "using aggregation" is a typical way to produce such numbers (to then create charts from them)), but you don't HAVE TO use aggregation (eg in cases such as yours). OK? PS: it might help to pinpoint your actual issue (= some setting or so that's wrong or missing?) if you'd update your question to include the entire view (in views export format) that you created so far (using "charts" also)

Comment: I've added the view export to my post.

Comment: OK, I'm done, I just added my "part 2" ... Curious about your extra feedback ...

Comment: Unfortunately, importing the first view gives me `Unable to interpret view code` and the second view gives me

`Field handler field_data_field_optionlist.field_optionlist is not available.
Field handler field_data_field_free_format_text.field_free_format_text is not available.
Sort criterion handler field_data_field_optionlist.field_optionlist_value is not available
..errors..
Sort criterion handler field_data_field_optionlist.field_optionlist_value is not available.
Filter criterion handler field_data_field_free_format_text.field_free_format_text_value is not available.
Unable to import view`

Comment: Pierre, did you have any luck importing my view?

Comment: Your error message tells me you did NOT adapt the machine names in my exported view to fit your names, like "field_year" that you should be using instead of (my) "field_optionlist" (same for the other field). Also, I did not try to import your view (I only looked at it to get the details I was looking for). But from what I saw, your exported view seems to not include any "style_plugin" that is different from a typical Views table (so not any "chart"-kind of plugin, as you can see in my exported views). Hang on a few mins, I'm going to further extend the last parg of my answer to clarify it.

Comment: I'd done further enhancing my answer ... your turn again ... let me know how it goes ...

Comment: Amazing Pierre.  For the first view I get "Unable to interpret view code" but the second view works perfect.  I need to figure out what is different about my view that was causing the values to all be zero.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems if I have FIELDS > Content: Products (Products) > STYLE SETTINGS > Use field template turned off in products only then the graphing works.  If that is turned on I get the zero value straight line.  Why that was turned on in the first place I don't know.  The query is the same whether it is on or off.  When I tried to make the settings the same as yours at some point I noticed the query started using JOIN.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the extra feedback. I seem to understand from lt that in the end, my answer did help to get it sorted out...